# Startup Growth Lite - How To Set Width For Content Type

Tags: 7, theming

I'm using the theme [Startup Growth Lite](https://www.drupal.org/project/startupgrowth_lite) for which we've created a content type but I can't find how/where to set it's default width. We want it to be the same width as the 'Basic Page' but for some some reason our content type is always much narrower as if it's expecting left & right sidebar content (I've checked the blocks and there are none assigned).

Pulling my hair out on this one!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Typical, minutes after posting the question I finally found the answer.

What has worked for me was adding my content type to the template.php file startupgrowth_lite_preprocess_page function, our content type was called 'client_work' which once added set it to display the same as the 'page' content type.

I added the following

```
&& $variables['node']->type != 'client_work'
```

to the end of the first *if* statement in the function below (around line 494).

```
function startupgrowth_lite_preprocess_page(&$variables) {

    /**
     * Insert variables into the page template.
     */
    if (isset($variables['node']) && $variables['node']->type != 'page' && $variables['node']->type != 'client_work') {
```